# Why didn't T'pol disrupt the terrorist broadcast of the Terra Prime leader

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

T'pol was standing inches away from the leader of a Xenophobic radical group as he was making terroristic threats, shooting the moon with his laser cannon, and labeling her baby as the ultimate threat.

[image]

Everyone on Earth was seeing the broadcast, as Starfleet Command and the Enterprise desparately attempted to block the broadcast, but could not.

Why didn't T'pol reach over and nerve pinch him, or make a snide remark, or even hold up her fingers as bunny ears behind his head to ruin the broadcast?

Tripp was also standing there careful not to interrupt the broadcast, but I mainly mention T'pol because she was closer, stronger, etc.

Comment: Isn't that Admiral Marcus?

Comment: @PointlessSpike It's the bad guy from the end of the series. They look kinda similar.

Comment: @PointlessSpike It has been suggested that he is Admiral Marcus's ancestor. This suggestion is often made when the same actor plays two characters of one species in two time periods. See also [Korrd](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Korrd) and [K'mpec](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/K'mpec).

Comment: I think it helps that they seem to have similar political views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that would prevent T'Pol (or Tucker) from taking unilateral action;

1) The potential threat to the baby

2) The number of people in the room (at least five, not including Paxton and any other flunkies just outside in the corridor)

3) The potential that a failed action would be met with another "demonstration" by Terra Prime and loss of life on Earth.